# Entity Framework. Just added a new field to DB, new field not saving from code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, webforms

I just added a new field to a table I have ("Leads")

Saving and retrieving  work fine for all fields except my new field that I added directly to the DB.  I'm doing the same thing for the new field as the other fields

```
objLead = new Leads();

objLead.PhoneNumber = txtPhoneNumber.Text; //this one works
objLead.MobilePhone = txtMobilePhone.Text; //this one doesn't

Leads ins = LeadsManager.Save(objLead);
```

my save function is..

```
    public static Leads Save(Leads objLead) {
        if (objLead.LeadId == 0) {

            //objLead.InsertBy = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
            objLead.InsertDate = DateTime.Now;
            objLead.InsertMachineInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
            DbContextHelper.DbContext.Add(objLead);
        }

        //secUser.UpdatedBy = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
        objLead.UpdateMachineInfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"].ToString();
        objLead.UpdateDate = DateTime.Now;
        DbContextHelper.DbContext.SaveChanges();

        return objLead;
    }
```

I'm fairly new to EF so I'm not sure if I'm missing something..  I went to the Leads class and added the new property so intellisense recoginzies when I put objLead.mobilePhone..  I'm just not sure why it's not saving to the DB..  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just curious which EF method are you using? Code first, model first, database first?  I probably won't be able to help either way, but you never know :O

Comment: DB First..  I inherited this project so I'm not 100% familiar with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding your column to your physical DB table perform the following steps:

1. Go into your model (.edmx)
2. Right click design area
3. Update Model from database...
4. Click the refresh tab on the dialog that appears
5. Finish

This should update your poco classes that were autogenerated previously with the new column that was added.  This *should* fix your issue if you're experiencing what I think you're experiencing.

Note that regenerating your POCOs in this manner will remove any changes that you did to them manually (if any).

EDIT:

I'm not sure if this actually works or not, but you could try it.  If you go directly into the POCO class created and add your new property with the correct data type, that might work.

Find your POCO classes by expanding your .edmx file from the solution explorer, then [modelName].tt, then select your [tableName].cs.

If you added a string to the table you could add:

```
public string NewColumnName { get; set; }
```

again I don't know if going this route actually works, refreshing your model based on the database is your best bet.

Comment: I'm hesitant to try that because I did that yesterday and  broke almost everything in my code..there were about 15 tables under the refresh tab. There was no way to go back either.  If I select just the one table it should only update that table alone?

Comment: Sorry, i don't think you can actually limit the update to specific objects, let me update the answer

Comment: Are you making any manual changes to your POCO classes? You shouldn't be getting breaking changes from model updates - at least I have yet to experience something like this.

Comment: THanks man that did it! Update model from database fixed.  I had a few error with datatypes not matching up correctly but once I fixed those, the same code that posted and now it's writing back. Thanks!